# Using nltk collocations as features in scikit-learn

Tags: nlp, nltk, text-processing, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I am trying to extract collocations using nltk from a corpus an then use their occurrences as features for a scikit-learn classifier.
Unfortunately I am not so familiar with nltk and I don't see an easy way to do this.
I got this far:

- extract collocations using `BigramCollocationFinder` from corpus
- for each document, extract all bigrams (using `nltk.bigrams`) and check if they are one of the collocations
- create a `TfidfVectorizer` with an analyzer that does nothing
- feed it the documents in form of the extracted bigrams

That seems pretty overcomplicated to me. Also it has the problem that the `BigramCollactionFinder` has a `window_size` parameter for bigrams that span over words. The standard `nltk.bigrams` extraction can not do that.

A way to overcome this would be to instantiate a new BigramCollocationFinder for each document and extract bigrams again and match them against the ones I found before... but again, that seems way to complicated.
Surely there is an easier way to do that, that I overlook.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

larsmans has already contributed a NLTK / scikit-learn feature mapper for simple, non collocation features. That might give you some inspiration for your own problem:

http://nltk.org/_modules/nltk/classify/scikitlearn.html